# How to show cell title in next controller with using segue?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` with labels in cells in storyboard. I want to show title from labels of selected cell in title of next controller. How to show title?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 8
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.destination is ViewController) {
        //code to showing title of my cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use prepareForSegue in swift and show cell title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981708/how-to-use-prepareforsegue-in-swift-and-show-cell-title)

Comment: Don't repost [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981708/how-to-use-prepareforsegue-in-swift-and-show-cell-title). Edit the question and add more information. In the question above it depends on where `prepare(for` is called from.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the destination ViewController inside your if statement like this:

```
//get destination view an set the title
let vc=segue.destination
//set title
vc.title="My Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to get selected cell:

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!
print(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
```

Comment: Don't get the data from the view (cell). Get it from the model (data source array).

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!        

    // Do not forgot to set cell tag.
    cell.tag = indexPath.row//cell tag has been set to indexpath.row

    return cell
    }
```

In order to navigate to your tableViewController implement PrepareForSegue like mentioned below.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {

    if segue.identifier == "Your_Identifier" {

    // Use this tag to pass data for the selected cell
    //this tag will act as indexpath.row

    guard let tag = (sender as? UIView)?.tag
    else {
     return
    }

let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController// change ViewController with your view controller

vc.title = YOUR_VALUE // get title for selected row from your array using tag. and 
//(vc.title) is the title of string type declared in next view controller

    // add the data you want to parse here.
    print(tag)
    }
    }
```

In the Next View Controller

You change the title by changing the title of the view controller being displayed:

Normally this is done in view did load on the view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = title //title is the property created by you
}
```